# Reading answer sheet with OMR by Mobile phone (Xamarin applcation)

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, omr

I wish to make a mobile app that will take a picture of a student’s answer sheet with OMR check boxes filled in.
And I want to then read the results of the answer sheet (which check boxes are marked) on the app. (offline, not using a web service, or api)

I'm using xamarin croos platrom application. (Androis and IOS)

how can i do this? Or, is there a tool for this solution?

Thanks.